# Do Pex and Moq work together nicley?

Tags: moq, pex

Has anyone tried this?

I like moq and i like what pex is doing, but haven't tried them together. I'd prefer to use moq over moles in most cases I think but am curious to see if anyone has hit roadblocks?

Do they play nice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integrate Pex with MoQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071091/integrate-pex-with-moq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I haven't tried, Pex and Moq should get along like old friends.

While the interception techniques between Pex and Moq are different (Pex uses the ProfilerAPI to interpret MSIL instructions; Moq uses DynamicProxy to dynamically derive classes) there are references in the Moq source code that suggest it was designed to prevent re-entrance problems where Pex would interfere with Moq.

According to the original [research paper for Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/guidancepexextensions.pdf), you can decorate your code with attributes that control when the Pex rewriter is used.

From the [Moq source code](http://code.google.com/p/moq/source/browse/trunk/Source/Mock.Generic.cs):

```
internal static MethodCall<T> Setup<T>(Mock mock, Expression<Action<T>> expression, Func<bool> condition) where T : class
{
    return PexProtector.Invoke(() =>
    {
       var methodCall = expression.ToMethodCall();
       var method = methodCall.Method;
       var args = methodCall.Arguments.ToArray();
       ThrowIfNotMember(expression, method);
       ThrowIfCantOverride(expression, method);

       var call = new MethodCall<T>(mock, condition, expression, method, args);
       var targetInterceptor = GetInterceptor(methodCall.Object, mock);
       targetInterceptor.AddCall(call, SetupKind.Other);

       return call;
     });   
 }
```

PexProtector is defined as:

```
 internal sealed class __ProtectAttribute : Attribute
 {
 }

 namespace Moq
 {
    [__Protect]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    internal static class PexProtector
    {
        public static void Invoke(Action action)
        {
           action();
        }

        public static T Invoke<T>(Func<T> function)
        {
           return function();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: the result is that they do behave very well together.

Answer (score 0):

i didnt get pex amd moq to work very well toghther, allthough that was a long time ago. Pex seemed to get lost in the Reflection.Emit / dynamic proxy stuff that moq creates.

i'd suggest looking at Moles if you need to do mocking in conjunction with pex. its a pretty nice mocking framework over all and is already bundled with pex